# Can ASP.NET validation controls display an exclamation point with tooltip message?

Tags: asp.net, validation

Can the standard ASP.NET Visual Studio validation  controls display an icon with a tool tip message instead of text, the way the WinForms ErrorProvider controls work?

If not, is the AjaxToolkit's ValidatorCallout control the best approach? Is this control flakey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need, already covered.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/RequiredTextBox.aspx

Comment: I'm surprised that this functionality isn't out-of-the-box by setting a property.